# Loop image in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

**MY CODE IN CONTROLLER :**

```
 public function image_item_name($inc) 
{
    if(isset($_POST['inc'])) {
        $inc = $_POST['inc'];
        $i = DB::select("SELECT file_name FROM tbl_image_item_name WHERE inc = '$inc';");

        foreach ($i as $a){ 

          echo '<img src="../../{{ $a[0]->file_name }}">';

        }
    }else {
        echo "Access Denied";
    }
```

The Problem :
I cannot to loop the image from database, please help me.

Comment: tried to add `->get()`? because, that way, you are only creating `QueryBuilder` instance..

Comment: how to write it sir? @BagusTesa

Comment: Share how you are calling `image_item_name()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some issues in your code

1. Your query is right but you don't need to access $a[0] you have retrieved a list of objects each object having a 'file_name' as a property so access it directly through $a->file_name .
2. {{ }} is a syntax designed for the blade template engine (i.e .blade.php files) you can't use them in ordinary .php files .
3. When coding in laravel stick into laravel way don't use native global php variables as $_GET and $_POST while you're having the 'request()' helper  .
4. Your query is so exposed to SQL Injection so **DON'T** use Raw SQL queries unless you surround them by prepared statements .

   ```
   public function image_item_name($inc) 
   {
   if(isset(request('inc'))) {
     $inc = request('inc');
     $i = DB::select("SELECT file_name FROM tbl_image_item_name WHERE inc = ?;",[$inc]);

   foreach ($i as $a){ 

       echo '<img src="../../'.$a->file_name.'">';

    }
   }  
   else {
          echo "Access Denied";
    }
   ```

Comment: so how sir? @omarfawzi

Comment: @DewaAditya, lets start with reading the [documentation first](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/), then create a proper model -- you can debug by calling `dd`. Next in course is to learn about the Laravel's View. That way, you can avoid abominable code that is an issue in itself and hard to read/debug - not to mention insecure. i'm afraid you brought this habit from another framework.. which is unclean..

Comment: Why function param is replaced ?

Comment: is that the path was right sir? i use laravel-5.6 and put the image at public/images @Salama96

Comment: Use function `asset()`

Answer (score -2):

try

```
$images = DB::table('tbl_image_item_name')->where('inc', $inc)->get();

foreach ($images as $image){ 

          echo '<img src="../{{ $image->file_name }}">';

        }
```

or eloquent way

```
$images = YourModelName::where('inc', $inc)->get();
```

Comment: Is it ordinary to inject {{}} which is a blade syntax in .php files ?

Comment: i dont think doing `echo '<img src="../{{ $image->file_name }}">';` will work.. since laravel will process the view (`.blade.php`) files into ordinary `.php` where the `{{ }}` is actually changed into `echo`.